# hive from_utc_timestamp returns wrong time

Tags: hive

I am using Hive and wants to get the UTC time.

By running

```
select date_format(to_utc_timestamp(bigint(1621446734295),'UTC'),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
```

It returns: `2021-05-20 01:52:14.295`.
However, this timestamp refers `2021-05-19 17:52:14.295 GMT`.

Why does the function `to_utc_timestamp` still returns time with timezone? Do I need to change some settings for Hive?

Comment: I am seeing this output `2021-05-19 18:52:14.295`, is timezone related settings are fine?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I think so...

Comment: Interesting.... I executed this: `select to_utc_timestamp(bigint(1621446734295), 'UTC'), cast(1621446734295 as timestamp) ` -  both timestamps should be equal and indeed they are. I got `2021-05-19 17:52:14.295`, the value is not equal to yours or @KoushikRoy

Comment: "this timestamp refers Wed, 19 May 2021 07:53:02 GMT." - any proof this is true? https://www.epochconverter.com/ also says it is 2021-05-19 17:52:14.295 GMT

Comment: Very strange, and i do not know why my time is 1 hour ahead of yours. Day light savings or British time - actually i am not very sure of my servers timezone.  But you are right. When i checked in https://demo.gethue.com/hue/editor/?type=6, its showing me this `2021-05-19 17:52:14.295`.

Comment: hey user2894829, how did you come up with  `Wed, 19 May 2021 07:53:02 GMT` ? It can not be this value in GMT.

Comment: Hi @KoushikRoy   Thanks for your reply. I made a mistake and updated the question

Comment: Hi @leftjoin Thanks for your reply. My bad and the question has been updated.